# changing value by button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just starting with JS and I found a function which changes the quantity of ingredients on a receipt. I want to change the value by clicking only the button.

I have included jquery. The classes are formatted accordingly and these are entered with a value as a dataBase value. The function now iterates through the index and multiplies the base value by the portion input.

```js
// Recipe calculator with jquery
function computeServing(serving) {
  $('.js-recipeIngredient').each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).children('span').html($(item)[0].dataset.basevalue * serving)
  })
}
$('#servingInput').on('change', function() {
  computeServing($(this).val())
})
$('.js-calcService').on('click', function() {
  var currentServing = $('#servingInput').val()
  $('#servingInput').val(currentServing)
  computeServing(currentServing)
})

computeServing(4)
```

```css
.Recipe-IngredientList {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.Recipe-Ingredient {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.Recipe-Ingredient:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.Recipe-Ingredient span {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<h3>Recipe</h3>
<div>
  <label for="serving">Portions :</label>
  <input type="number" id="servingInput" value="4">
  <button id="js-calcService">Portionen</button>


  <div class="Recipe-IngredientList">
    <div class="Recipe-Ingredient js-recipeIngredient" data-baseValue="100">Farine : <span></span>g</div>
    <div class="Recipe-Ingredient js-recipeIngredient" data-baseValue="2">Oeuf : <span></span></div>
    <div class="Recipe-Ingredient js-recipeIngredient" data-baseValue="150">Lait : <span></span>mL</div>
    <div class="Recipe-Ingredient js-recipeIngredient" data-baseValue="50">Lardon : <span></span>g</div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Can anybody give me a hint how I can make the calculation work with the button?

Thanks!
Maris

Comment: need to see your code, what have you tried, what are your expected results

Comment: What's wrong with the button? The script seems to work just fine. You can just simplify that one: `$('.js-calcService').on('click', function() {
  computeServing($('#servingInput').val())
})`

Answer (score 1):

Besides you could improve the button's click function to:

```js
$('.js-calcService').on('click', function() {
  computeServing($('#servingInput').val())
});
```

the presented code seems to work just fine.

Another advice would be to use the `"input"` Event. This way you won't need any button at all:

```js
// Recipe calculator with jquery
const $servingInput = $('#servingInput');

function computeServing(amount) {
  const serving = amount ?? parseFloat($servingInput.val() || 1);
  $('.js-recipeIngredient').each((i, item) => {
    $(item).find('span').html(Number(item.dataset.basevalue) * serving)
  });
}

$servingInput.on('input', computeServing); // Do on input
computeServing(); // Do on page load
```

```css
.Recipe-IngredientList {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.Recipe-Ingredient {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.Recipe-Ingredient:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.Recipe-Ingredient span {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<label for="serving"><span>Portions:</span> <input type="number" id="servingInput" value="4"></label>

<div class="Recipe-IngredientList">
  <div class="Recipe-Ingredient js-recipeIngredient" data-baseValue="100">Farine: <span></span>g</div>
  <div class="Recipe-Ingredient js-recipeIngredient" data-baseValue="2">Oeuf: <span></span></div>
  <div class="Recipe-Ingredient js-recipeIngredient" data-baseValue="150">Lait: <span></span>mL</div>
  <div class="Recipe-Ingredient js-recipeIngredient" data-baseValue="50">Lardon: <span></span>g</div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Roko!

If i remove this code to my external file script.js I get an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

What I have done wrong? Could you help?

Comment: @ChristianMazilu order of libraries inclusion matters! Right **before** the closing `</body>` tag first link to the jQuery library; then link to your `script.js` file: `<script src="jquery.js"></script><script src="script.js"></script>` - This way `jQuery` and `$` will be recognised as global variables and can be than used from your other files.